# Get URL of Solid DataBase for JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a Solid Database. And I want to connect to this DB by **JDBC**. How can I get URL for connection creation?

**[EDIT]**

For more information:
[SOLID JDBC Driver 
Programmer's Guide](http://www.cs.tut.fi/lintula/manual/java/jdbc/jdbcprguide.htm)

[SOLID JDBC Driver 2.3 Readme](http://www.cs.tut.fi/lintula/manual/java/jdbc/jdbcreadme.htm)

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Registering JDBC Driver**

The JDBC driver manager, which is written entirely in Java, handles loading and unloading drivers and interfacing connection requests with the appropriate driver. It was JavaSoft's intention to make the use of a specific JDBC driver as transparent as possible to the programmer and user.

The driver can be registered with the three alternative ways, which are shown below. The parameter required by Class.forName and Properties.put functions is the name of the driver, which is solid.jdbc.SolidDriver.

```
// registration using Class.forName service
Driver)Class.forName("solid.jdbc.SolidDriver")

// a workaround to a bug in some JDK1.1 implementations
Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("solid.jdbc.SolidDriver").newInstance();

// Registration using system properties variable also
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.put("jdbc.drivers", "solid.jdbc.SolidDriver");
System.setProperties(p);
```

**Connecting to the database**

Once the driver is succesfully registered with the driver manager a connection is established by creating a Java Connection object with the following code. The parameter required by the DriverManager.getConnection function is the JDBC connection string.

```
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(sCon);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Connect failed : " + e.getMessage());
    throw new Exception("Halted.");
}
```

The connect string  structure is jdbc:solid://://. The string "jdbc:solid://fb9:1314/dba/dba" attempts to connect a SOLID Server in machine fb9 listening tcp/ip protocol at port 1314.

The application can establish several Connection  objects to database. Connections can be closed be the following code.

```
conn.close();
```